# How should I use the cursor in the Function?

Tags: sql, oracle, function, cursor

I want to use the cursor in the package's function like this:

```
PACKAGE PKG
AS
TYPE RESULT_T
IS
  TABLE OF varchar2(30);
FUNCTION GENERATEF
  RETURN RESULT_T PIPELINED;
END PKG;
/
create or replace
PACKAGE BODY PKG
AS
FUNCTION GENERATEF
  RETURN RESULT_T PIPELINED
IS
BEGIN
  FOR TLC IN (select name from users)
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW(TLC.name);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN;
END;
END PKG;
/
SELECT * FROM TABLE(PKG.GENERATEF);
```

I think right now the issue is focusing on the

```
select name from users
```

because if I use

```
select sysdate from dual
```

the function works well.

If I want to extract  data from other VIEW, it will bring some error like this:

> Error(7,45): PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist".

But actually, the view exists.

I don't know where is the problem. And I'm not sure whether it's OK to use the cursor like I mentioned.

Comment: It works for me http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/22bb1/1 . What happens when you just run the query `select name from users` ? are you sure you have the right grants (select)?

Comment: If you can select from `users` but the package can't see it, then that might imply it's in a different schema and your privileges on it are granted via a role, which is ignored in a definer's rights package (as explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#i18574).

Comment: Thanks for your clarify. I'm not sure whether it's caused by the privileges issue. The Users View is listed in the "Other Users" Navigation of sql developer. If it's privilege problem, do I have some other solution? For example, create another same table that stores the Users information?

Comment: @rida - if you don't have a public synonym then you might need to select `from <schema>.users`, even when you run it standalone. Check/fix that first, and then make sure you have the select priv granted directly to whoever owns the package (or build it with invoker's rights as that link describes). It isn't clear what's wrong at the moment.

Comment: @AlexPoole, thanks for your advice. and right now, I've checked my schema is ops$e01522, and the view's name is ard113$curr.ae. But when I want to select in the ops$e01522.ard113$curr.ae. It still can't work. The message is ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. I'm not sure whether the expression is OK for extracting the data from the schema's view.

Comment: @Rida - dont't give both schemas, you would select from `ard113curr.ae`, if that really is the schema.

Comment: @AlexPoole, finally, I think I have to create the same table that the function can recognize. I'm not sure whether it's the better way. But I think it can solve the issue.

Comment: @Rida - are you sure you don't need the data from the other schema's table? Depends where you are in the dev cycle of course, maybe you do need this. If you expect to get the data from another schema then you need select privs on that table (directly, not from a role) and either to qualify the reference with the schema name or have a synonym (alias).

Comment: @AlexPoole I need extract the data from other schema's table. But I'm not sure why I can't extract the data from the tables or views in the function field.